# Anything like canvas.drawWindow() in WebKit?

Tags: javascript, webkit

Does anybody know if there are plans to add something comparable to [Mozilla's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas#Additional_Features)

```
canvas.drawWindow()
```

to WebKit?

I wasn't able to find info about this on [WebKit's mailing lists](http://www.google.com/search?q=drawWindow+site%3alists.webkit.org&hl=en&qscrl=1&num=100&lr=&ft=i&cr=&safe=off) or elsewhere.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are developing a Google Chrome extension then you should check this:

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-captureVisibleTab

---

If you are building a web page then you should check this:

http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: I was looking for a pure-web solution and html2canvas looks quite promising... thanks!

Comment: A word of warning, It's a bit slow, especially on mobile devices. בהצלחה

Answer (score 3):

As MDN states:

> This feature is only available for code
>   running with Chrome privileges. It is
>   not allowed in normal HTML pages.

*Note: Chrome in this case refers to Firefox's User Interface.*

This is mainly a feature that Mozilla has added for AddOns. I could, for example, imagine that an AddOn would render the WebSite onto the canvas and then get the ImageData(maybe do some processing before that) and then save it to disk. Useful for saving screen shots of WebPages or even doing Testing of Layout.

So since this is an Mozilla Extension and not a standard by any means, I see little(read: no) chances for it to be implemented by WebKit, you may want to file a bug for Chromium(http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) if you really want it for extension development, but even then you would not be able to use it in every day web pages.

Comment: Thanks! I'm aware of the fact that it's only used in AddOns (for security reasons) but I was hoping that maybe WebKit have plans to offer a similar functionality and extend it beyond Mozilla's scope. As for standards compliance, WebKit do offer some non-standard extensions to CSS, don't they? Since I'm only targeting iOS & Android at the moment, a non-standard, WebKit-only solution is good enough for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to keep look into the WHATWG discussion.

http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2011-March/030862.html

I'm also try to implement html2canvas solution or the low level solution  + . But in case of long page, is killing the web app.

Just for additional reading you can keep a look at:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas
http://robert.ocallahan.org/2011/02/distinguishing-versus-web-resources_02.html